# How to get rid of Thunderbird error "[NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: Trash"

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

Every time I start Thunderbird, I get this error:

[image]

> The current operation on 'Trash' did
>   not succeed. The mail server for
>   account spamspam@gmail.com responded:
>   [NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: Trash
>   (now in authenticated state)
>   (Failure).

I've figured out that it goes away if I create folders in my Gmail accounts called "[Imap]/Trash" and "[Imap]/Sent", but why are these necessary?  Even if I tell Thunderbird to unsubscribe from them, it still notices when I remove the labels and starts popping up this error again.

One account also complains if I remove the "Sent Items" label.

Answer (score 3):

I  finally found the way to make this work

So that the Thunderbird will work and get all data including syb folders
Follow these steps :

Browse to : `tools > account settings > server settings > advanced button >`
UN-check the setting : `allow server to override these name spaces` 
(so it would not be checked! by default it is)
Press `ok`

Browse to : `file > subscribe > press : subscribe > ok`

You should then get all the folders content + sub folders etc. into your Thunderbird
* I have also created a folder in Thunderbird > and checked Google > it synced

Hopefully this will help you
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the Account Settings, Copies & Folders you can change the location of any of these, you can even set them to local folders.

Comment: They are already set to IMAP folders like `[Gmail]/Sent Mail`, but Thunderbird still complains if `[Imap]/Sent` is deleted.

Comment: The closest answer I found is this: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=949895&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a
I have never had this problem show up even when removing my folders on the mail server next sync of Thunderbird updates them.